# "pecl http" php extension can't be loaded in local (xampp/wampp)

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, php-extension, pecl

I want to add the php "http" extension to xampp on Windows
(https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http/4.2.2/windows). But every time I get the error in my console :

```bash
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'http' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\http (Le module sp├®cifi├® est introuvable), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_http.dll (Le module sp├®cifi├® est introuvable)) in Unknown on line 0        PHP 8.1.27 (cli) (built: Dec 19 2023 23:28:30) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64) Copyright (c) The PHP GroupZend Engine v4.1.27, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I follow the correct procedure for adding a php extension. I download the compatible .dll (in my case Thread Safe x64 for php 8.1), put it in the "`xampp\php\ext`" folder, then declare it in php.ini as follows: `extension=http`and finally I restart the Apache server.

I checked by going to http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php the necessary configuration and I'm in TS x64.

[Catpure php info xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEnDl.png)

When I realized that I was using php 8.2 on xampp and that the latest pecl DLL was for 8.1 I tried to downgrade and download an 8.1 version by going to https://windows.php.net/download/.J I tested by downloading 8.1.27 (the only one visible on the 8.1 page) and then installing it on xampp but even that didn't work I still got the same error.

I miss surely something in the configuration ?
If you have any ideas I'd love to hear from you.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wrote an [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/php-8-setup-php_ssh2/) on how to debug this problem. The article is about SSH, but it applies to any PHP extension DLL on Windows. Tip: The `PHP Extension` version must match PHP and the extension. The extension must be version `20210902` in your case. That is set when the extension is compiled.

Comment: Thank you ! I read your article and I understand better the problem. But At my current level, I tried to compile the .dll myself, but I haven't succeeded yet on Windows - it's a disaster ... And I can't find any other compatible .dll on the Internet to download. Do you have any link or something useful to compile a .dll ? Even if I have to do a a virtual machine  like Debian ?

Comment: No, just my document. If you want help you must clearly define what does not work. You now know the problem, create a new question on building PHP extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution is to compile the .dll ourselves because the API version php of the extension compiled doesn't match with my current php version installed. Link of the [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/php-8-setup-php_ssh2/) of John Hanley which explains it.

I post another question here for it because I haven't managed to compile on Windows yet : [Building an extension php .dll (ext_http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139446/building-an-extension-php-dll-ext-http)