# Building an extension php .dll (ext_http)

Tags: php, pecl, gnuwin32

I had already asked a question about this ([Question extension relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880050/pecl-http-php-extension-cant-be-loaded-in-local-xampp-wampp)) so the only solution was to compile the .dll myself on Windows.
I want to compile the .dll for the PECL http extension on Windows.

However, I clearly can't build it with all the tutorials I see, I always have problems with version conflicts between all the software I need to download.

From all the tutorials I've been watching I've followed this method but I must be doing something wrong:

- Download **Visual Studio Build Tools 2019** (https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202019) which would allow you to compile
- First take the php version you want and download "Development package" (or the debug pack). I took the php version 8.1.26
- Declare the root folder path in (e.g. "C://php-8-1") the PATH in the user's environment variables
- Download the PECL extension source folder (i.e. ext_http) and extract it

After all these downloads I start the procedure:

- Open the extracted PECL extension folder with visual studio's native terminal ("x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019") as administrator.
- Launch : `phpize` then `configure`
After launch `configure` an error : "bison.exe is required" The only viable version I found was GnuWin32 (Bison: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32).

After relaunch `configure`, another error appeared saying that bison.exe had to be of a more recent version, or at **least 3.0.0**, and the only existing Windows setup for Bison was max 2.4.1.

From then on, it was never-ending: we had to compile the bison.exe for Windows ourselves, and that's when I started to give up ...

If anyone has a viable tutorial or say me if I misunderstood something, I'd love it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my GitHub repo, I have detailed build instructions for Windows: https://github.com/jhanley-com/php-ssh2-windows

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to build following the instructions, everything works except for the configure command.
For my purpose I have the command: `configure --enable-cli --enable-zlib --with-openssl --enable-apache2-4handler --enable-http=shared`
But it displays a lot of warnings on a lot of extension like "zip not enabled; libraries and headers not found" and it will explain why the final final command `nmake` doesn't work. I have to build also others extension too ?

Comment: Just in case, here's the `nmake` error:
`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: Unable to open input file 'C:\php-dev\php-8.1.27RC1-src\php-8.1.27RC1-src\x64\Release_TS\php8ts.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe"' : code retour '0x49d'
Stop.`

Comment: UDDATE : I retried and now the only warning I have with the `configure` command is `Checking for library zlib.lib;zlib_a.lib ... <in deps path> \lib\zlib_a.lib
        raphf not found: raphf support in http disabled
WARNING: curl convenience functions not enabled; libraries and headers not found`. 
But I have the same error on launch ``nmake``. Indeed the file php8ts.lib is not generated in the directory  so I continue to search

Comment: Please delete your comments and edit your question with new details. Also, update your question with the current problem so that we do not need to figure out the trail of changes. Post one clearly defined problem with all necessary details.